# Explicit expression of eigenvalue and eigenvector of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory

Could any one tell me what kind of graph has the explicit expression of its eigenvalue and eigenvector? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you want. If it's just a list of graphs then:
(a) Paths. (b) Cayley graphs for abelian groups. (c) Strongly regular graphs.

There are other classes, but these would be the simplest.

Comment: Recently, I'm looking at the perturbed version of Laplacian matrix by adding a diagonal matrix whose diagonal element has only one 1 and 0 for the rest. It seems that the eigenvector of this perturbed Laplacian matrix can tell the importance of node in a graph.

Comment: For example, if you want to calculate the score for node k, just add a diagonal matrix with only kth column and kth row element 1 and 0 for the rest, then the score of node k is the absolute value of kth element in the eigenvector of smallest eigenvalue of the perturbed Laplacian matrix. Due to the fact that the eigenvector for general graph Laplacian is not explicit, I want to check those graphs whose Laplacian eigenvector is explicit. Thanks!

Comment: So you want graphs for which we can explicitly write down the eigenvector belonging to the minimum eigenvalue of $L+D$, where $L$ is the Laplacian and $D$ is diagonal with $D_{i,i}=1$ and all other entries zero?

Comment: Yes, exactly! If we denote the eigenvector of this minimum eigenvalue of $L+D$ by $v_1$, then it seems that the absolute value of its $i$-th entry(if it is real) $|v_1(i)|$ say something about the importance of the $i$-th node in the graph.